# Using Cases from the book Basic Image Processing in Mathematica

Tags: import, image, compatibility

In the book "Basic Image Processing in Mathematica" written for *Mathematica* 10 and earlier, the author does this:

```
robot = Import[
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Robot_banana.\
jpg", "ImageWithExif"]
```

Then he does this:

```
"ExposureTime" /. 
 Cases[Options[robot], HoldPattern["ExposureTime" -> __], Infinity]
```

However, I am using *Mathematica* 11.2, so the output is `"ExposureTime"` instead of (1/5)s. I've tried a couple of things, reading the documentation on `Cases`, and viewing the content:

```
Options[root]
```

I also tried:

```
Cases[Options[robot], HoldPattern["ExposureTime" -> __], Infinity]
```

But that returns `{}` (the empty set).

Can someone explain why this doesn't work in *Mathematica* 11.2?

Answer (score 6):

The exif information is now encoded into an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association), and an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) is an atomic object. [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases) cannot search inside atomic objects, and so your code doesn't work. Here are two approaches that will work in M11.2:

```
exif = Import[
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Robot_banana.jpg",
    "Exif"
];
exif["ExposureTime"]
```

> Quantity[1/5, "Seconds"]

```
robot = Import[
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Robot_banana.jpg",
    "ImageWithExif"
];
exif = OptionValue[Options[robot], MetaInformation];
exif["Exif", "ExposureTime"]
```

> Quantity[1/5, "Seconds"]

Comment: Beautiful answer. However, I don't understand the phrase "Cases cannot search inside atomic objects." Here is an example from the documentation: `Cases[{<|a -> 1|>, <|b -> 2|>, <|c -> 1|>}, <|x_ -> 1|> -> x]`. And there are several other use of Cases with Association objects in the documentation.

Comment: @David, that works, but this doesn't: `Cases[{<|a -> 1|>, <|b -> 2|>, <|c -> 1|>}, (x_ -> 1) -> x]`. Hence "cannot search inside".

Answer (score 5):

The following should work in versions 10.x and 11.x:

```
Fold[Replace[#2, #1] &, Options[robot, MetaInformation],
     {MetaInformation, "Exif", "ExposureTime"}]
```

For me, it returns `1/5` in 10.4, and `Quantity[1/5, "Seconds"]` in 11.2.